# Is it possible to use JHipster with Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jhipster

I just discovered JHipster which looks fantastic : http://www.jhipster.tech

I am used to develop with Gradle, SpringBoot and Groovy.

That's why I'm asking if it's possible to use Groovy in a project generated with JHipster.

Comment: JHipster generates a spring boot project in java, so as long as you are used to mix both languages, I don't see any road blocker.

Comment: And if in doubt put any preexisting java source files under the groovy root.  The groovyc will handle both and spare yourself the trouble of having two sources and maybe circular dependencies